# Research Areas which combine Computer Science with Physics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, computational-physics, education

Throughout my high school i loved physics very very much. I always wanted to a PhD in physics. Along with i thought of pursuing space science. But due certain reasons i ended up in Computer Science. I have started with the third year of my bachelors degree. I don't hate computer Science, it's just that i loved physics a lot

Are there research areas (I have always wanted to do research) which combine Physics and Computer Science?

​

1. I talked to some of my friends who are good coders and they suggested me to get into making apps that simulate certain physics fundae. But that is not what i want. I would want to stress again that i liked actual physics. So i don't think i would enjoy just simulating stuff. I am more of a research kinda guy not an application oriented person.
2. Once again i want to stress that it is not at all that i hate computer science or i consider it bad. It's just that i want to do what i loved more and rather than completely changing my stream (which is difficult as well as risky and above all makes me guilty conscious as i would waste four whole years), i want to strike a balance between what i want and what i have.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine Physics and Computer Science?" Do you just want to know what areas of Physics make heavy use of software? Or what types of physicists might write code?

Comment: Are there fields of physics that use programming? Sure, pretty much all of them. Which makes this type of question kinda useless because it's not really helpful to make a list of things. Personalized suggestions are also considered off-topic.

Comment: The term "Computational Physics" is often used (if you want to google for something). Pretty much any problem outside of the two-body problem can not be solved exactly and so if you want to make progress you have to use computers to help. The level of computer usage can really be up to you.

Comment: *So i don't think i would enjoy just simulating stuff* That's literally what computational physics does, so I'm not sure what you're dreaming we do instead...

Comment: Hi Sarbajeet and welcome to stackexchange :) Mostly people prefer questions involving calculations or conceptual physics questions. For advice on your situation, you can try physicsforums.com for example. As for your question, it's currently easier to find research opportunities involving computational physics than just about anything else! So you should have no problem with this. Though, most of it does involve simulation in some way or another. What sort of thing did you have in mind with non-simulation physics computer programs? e.g. In math they use computers to check many possibilities..

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all experimental physics these days. Sometimes we're sifting through voluminous data looking for exceptional events. Other times, we're making elaborate numerical models, seeing if we can match to data. Very few  experiments involve checking small data sets against pencil and paper calculations.

Comment: Basically all theoretical as well, I'd say.

Comment: Using software to do physics is not the same thing as Computer Science. This might be why you got a downvote (I didn't downvote).

Comment: Computer Science is a separate discipline and it's pretty clear from working in computational physics that most physicists have no idea about computer science (or software engineering for that matter).

Comment: I downvoted because it's a partial answer to a useless question.

Comment: @hft "most physicists have no idea about computer science (or software engineering for that matter)". That's a reason to involve more computer scientists.

Comment: @JohnDoty Yeah sure, but you wrote "Pretty much all experimental physics these days." Not sure what that is supposed to imply.

Comment: @hft a corollary to "physicists have no idea about comp sci" is that comp scientists generally have no idea about physics (at least to the level of being useful for research purposes).

Comment: @KyleKanos Indeed, but that's true of all enabling professions. Sometimes we work with chemists, engineers, pilots, ... It's good to be able to bring in the expertise needed.

Comment: @john Given a choice between hiring a PhD in your subfield and a CS major whose last physics course was probably in HS (in undergrad, if you're lucky) and would require a lot of hand-holding for a multitude of months, if not the entire duration, who are you going to pick as your postdoc? (*hint: you're lying if you said the CS student.*)

Comment: @KyleKanos If I was expecting one postdoc to do the whole project, I'd go for a physicist, certainly. But I work on space missions: they require diverse teams.